# How can I change the pane from Vertical to Horizontal format in MS Visio 2003

Tags: microsoft-visio

I want to create a business process chart in MS Visio 2003.The pane is in Vertical format and I wish to change it to horizontal format

Answer (score 0):

menu File -> Page Setup

and select **Landscape**